# How to add XML elements into the toolbox in Visual Studio 2010 RC

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd

I'm trying to edit an XML schema in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC, but when I go to the toolbox (with the schema open and focused) there's absolutely nothing in the Toolbox view, even when every tutorial out there that I've read tells me that there should be. I've tried using the context menu option for resetting the Toolbox to no effect.  Is there something I'm missing ? Something I need to install to get this feature of Visual Studio going ?

Comment: I am also having this problem.  Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This an old question, I know, but for anyone that comes across this looking for the XML Schema tab in the Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox: There is none.  Microsoft didn't include it in the newer versions of Visual Studio and they don't seem to have plans to add one.  I'm using a similar tool provided with Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php (pick a package with XML Tools).

Answer (score 0):

be sure your XML Designer is in schema view when you have your xsd file open in visual studio. you can make sure its open this way by right-clicking the xsd file and selecting open with --> xml schema editor